# Python unittest ModuleNotFoundError when importing 'snowflake.connector'

Tags: python, python-unittest, anaconda3, snowflake-connector

I'm working on a python project using anaconda, and when I import snowflake.connector in the project, unittest fails. I haven't been able to reproduce the example with a different package, just snowflake.connector.

I'm using python version 3.9.2.

I'm able to minimally reproduce the error with the following directory setup:

```
/wtf
  __init__.py
  /dir1
    __init__.py
    stuff.py
/test
  __init__.py
  /test_dir1
    __init__.py
    test_stuff.py
```

stuff.py:

```
import snowflake.connector

def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

test_stuff.py:

```
import unittest
from wtf.dir1.stuff import add

class Test_Stuff(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_add(self):
        result = add(1,2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 3)
```

Running from the terminal, I get the following :

```
> conda run -n envname python -m unittest
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(41): `conda run python -m unittest` failed. (See above for error)
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test.test_dir1.test_stuff (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test.test_dir1.test_stuff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sam.helmich\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\sam.helmich\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\sam.helmich\git\wtf\test\test_dir1\test_stuff.py", line 2, in <module>
    from wtf.dir1.stuff import add
  File "C:\Users\sam.helmich\git\wtf\wtf\dir1\stuff.py", line 1, in <module>
    import snowflake.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: are you able to import "snowflake.connector" in the conda python shell?

Comment: Yes, without issue.

Comment: @HussainBohra your question got me thinking, and I found something interesting. If I activate the conda environment and run `python -m unittest`, everything runs fine, but if I'm outside the environment and run `conda run -n env_name python -m unittest` it doesn't work!